# C# Set Textbox Value to Table Query from Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

So I'm able to access my azure table without issue, as the console.writeline displays the data I'm seeking to pull.
What I need to do Is query my azure table storage and then spit the result out into a textbox. My code is as follows:

```
               //start of code
               CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
               CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=telephony;AccountKey=RandomKeyhere);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TelephonyIssueLog");
        await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        //This is the code I'm having troubles with.
        TableQuery<IssueEntity> query = new TableQuery<IssueEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Issues"));
        textBox1.Text = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToString();
```

Comment: `table.ExecuteQuery(query)` would return a collection of matching entities. I am not sure why you would want to display them in a textbox. A more ideal scenario would be to display this result in a grid. Would you mind explaining your scenario?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, 

Thank you for your reply. Displaying the item to a grid or column chart would actually be ideal. I haven't gotten that far in the function, however. My ultimate goal is to use azure table storage with Microsoft Chart Tools to import the data received from Azure table Storage.

However, the challenge I am facing is that there is truly a lack of example code using both tools together, so I am trying to piece things together.
Would you have an idea on how to put queried data into a column chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My ultimate goal is to use azure table storage with Microsoft Chart Tools to import the data received from Azure table Storage.

I assume that you want to add Microsoft Chart control to your Windows Forms or Web application. If I misunderstand it, please tell me what is the Microsoft Chart Tools you mentioned.

Here is a Windows Forms Application for you to have a better understanding of how to put queried data into a [Basic Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx).

**DemoForm.cs**

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GenerateChart(this.DemoChart, LoadData());
}

/// <summary>
/// Load data from Azure Table
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private IList<MetricEntity> LoadData()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BruceChenStorageConnectionString"));
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("TelephonyIssueLog");
    cloudTable.CreateIfNotExists();
    TableQuery<MetricEntity> query = new TableQuery<MetricEntity>()
        .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Issues"));
    return cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
}

/// <summary>
/// Generate the column chart with the specified data source
/// </summary>
/// <param name="chart"></param>
/// <param name="dataItems"></param>
private void GenerateChart(Chart chart, IEnumerable<MetricEntity> dataItems)
{
    chart.Series.Clear();
    chart.Titles.Add(
        new Title("Demo Chart for loading data from Azure Table"));
    List<string> xValues = new List<string>() { "MetricA", "MetricB", "MetricC" };
    foreach (var item in dataItems)
    {
        Series series = new Series() { Name = item.UserName };
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        series.Points.DataBindXY(xValues, new List<int>() {
          item.MetricA,
          item.MetricB,
          item.MetricC});
        chart.Series.Add(series);
    }
}
```

**MetricEntity.cs**

```
public class MetricEntity : TableEntity
{
    public MetricEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
    }
    public MetricEntity() { }
    public int MetricA { get; set; }
    public int MetricB { get; set; }
    public int MetricC { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**Data structure in Azure Table Storage**

[image]

When you click the button and invoke the btnLoad_Click, you could get the following result:

[image]